# Create a new DataFrame column from a condition of an existing one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe consisting of 3 columns: Longitude, Latitude and area.

```
CELL NAME   Longitude   Latitude    area

LE1072_012  -0.072457   61.042381   6.170170e-01
LE1437_011  1.711201    60.936088   5.960055e-01
LE2614_012  0.071279    58.835267   4.412428e-01
LE2826_013  1.558309    60.730385   2.844340e-01
LE2346_011  -1.056118   59.646612   2.528572e-01
LE2676_012  -0.198150   58.546112   2.395335e-01
LE2526_012  0.594452    59.184265   2.392216e-01
....
```

I need a fourth column that depends on the value of area. If area is greater than a threshold it should say 'rural' and if it is smaller 'urban'

I wanted to implement it as a function with an if

```
def CellType(area):
        if area > threshold
           a='rural'
        else
           a='urban'
        return a
```

and then call it this way

```
df['CellType']=CellType(df['area'])
```

This way I get an error that says that the conditional of a series is ambiguous

Then I tried this piece of code

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['area'][i]<0.002:
        df['CellType'][i]='urban'
    else:
        df['CellType'][i]='rural'
```

This works, but it takes forever when I run this on 15k cells

Is there a way to make this task faster?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` that return elements chosen depending on condition. The first parameter is **your condition**, the second is the return if the condition is **True**, the last is if condition is **False**

```
df['CellType'] = np.where(df['area'] < 0.002, 'urban','rural')
```

Comment: Hi! While this may provide an answer, it is generally discouraged on StackOverflow to leave code only answers. Please explain why this is a solution as it will help OP and future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: @d_kennetz My mistake, i add explanation to the answer. Thanks for the tip

Comment: That looks a lot better, I hope you can see how this is more beneficial!

Comment: Thanks Terry!, It worked perfectly and in the test for 5k cells took

Wall time: 3.46 ms

instead of the 7 min it took before